How do you change state outside of Component in React?
I want to create a Ball component whose position (as rendered by its CSS) gets updated every time I call the swap function in a different view called InsertionSortView. How do I do that?
Here's my Ball code:
import CSS from "csstype";
import { useState } from "react";

const circleAroundNumber: CSS.Properties = {
  borderRadius: "50%",
  width: "70px",
  height: "70px",
  padding: "8px",
  position: "absolute",

  textAlign: "center",

  fontSize: "32px",
};

interface Props {
  num: number;
  positionx: string;
  positiony: string;
  ballColor: string;
}

function Ball({ num, positionx, positiony, ballColor }: Props) {
  //hooks
  const [colorOfBall, setBallColor] = useState({ ballColor });
  const [xposition, setxposition] = useState({ positionx });
  const [yposition, setyposition] = useState({ positiony });
  const [numValue, setnumValue] = useState({ num });

  const combinedStyles: CSS.Properties = {
    ...circleAroundNumber,
    background: ballColor,
    left: positionx,
    top: positiony,
  };

  return <div style={combinedStyles}>{num}</div>;
}

export default Ball;


Here's my InsertionSortView code:
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import Ball from "../components/Ball";

interface viewProps {
  balls: (typeof Ball)[];
}

interface swapProps {
  ball1: typeof Ball;
  ball2: typeof Ball;
}

const swap = ({ ball1, ball2 }: swapProps): [typeof Ball, typeof Ball] => {
  //want to get position of ball1 and ball2

  //hardcoded values
  let ball1positionx: number = 30;
  let ball1positiony: number = 100;
  let ball2positionx: number = 90;
  let ball2positiony: number = 100;
  let middle: number = (ball1positionx + ball2positionx) / 2;
  const maxHeight: number = 20;
  while (ball1positionx === 90 && ball1positiony === 100) {
    if (ball1positionx < middle) {
      ball1positionx += 3;
      ball1positiony -= 8;
      ball2positionx -= 3;
      ball1positiony -= 8;
    } else if (ball1positionx >= middle) {
      ball1positionx += 3;
      ball1positiony += 8;
      ball2positionx -= 3;
      ball1positiony += 8;
    }
    //render new balls
    let newBall1 = React.createElement(Ball, {
      // props object
      positionx: ball1positionx.toString(),
      positiony: ball1positiony.toString(),
      ballColor: "red",
      num: 7,
    });
  }
  return [ball1, ball2];
};

function InsertionSortView({ balls }: viewProps) {}

export default InsertionSortView;


I've tried playing around with state, but I can't seem to access the ball's state outside of the Ball Component. I've also thought of putting the swap function, which is what I want to use the Ball's state, inside the Ball Component, but that wouldn't make sense since swap takes two instances of "Ball".

I'm assuming you're trying to animate the balls swapping place given the while loop and increments? I would recommend reading up on how prop-passing works in React, as well as the general event loop/requestAnimationFrame in browsers, as it seems like you're making some fundamental mistakes here with your setup. In general you shouldn't be updating visuals in synchronous while loops, and you shouldn't update internal React component state outside of React-land.
